# How to put spaces in a stringbuilder

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

Hello I have following method to display a promotion line when I comment a shoutbox:

```
public String getShoutboxUnderline(){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("watch");
        builder.append("on");
        builder.append("youtube");
        builder.append(":");
        builder.append("Mickey");
        builder.append("en");
        builder.append("de");
        builder.append("stomende");
        builder.append("drol");

        return builder.toString();
    }
```

But when I get it, I get watchonyoutube:mickeyendestomendedrol, which is without spaces. How do I get spaces in my Stringbuilder?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

As of JDK 1.8, you can use a [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html), which is more convenient in your case:

> `StringJoiner` is used to construct a sequence of characters separated
>   by a **delimiter** and **optionally** starting with a supplied prefix and
>   ending with a supplied suffix.

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(" "); // Use 'space' as the delimiter
joiner.add("watch") // watch 
      .add("on") // watch on 
      .add("youtube") // watch on youtube
      .add(":") // etc...
      .add("Mickey")
      .add("en")
      .add("de")
      .add("stomende")
      .add("drol");

return joiner.toString();
```

This way, you will not need to add those spaces "manually".

Comment: Note: This solution is valid only if you're using Java 1.8 and up

Answer (score 7):

Just invoke `builder.append(" ")` at the location of your preference.

E.g.

```
builder
    .append("watch")
    .append(" ")
    .append("on")
```

...etc.

NB:

- Using the fluent builder syntax here for convenience
- You can also just append a space after each literal instead (save for the last one)

Answer (score 2):

Cleaner way of doing it.

Create a class variable:

```
private static final String BLANK_SPACE=" ";
```

Now in you StringBuilder code ,append it where required:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("watch");
    builder.append(BLANK_SPACE);
    builder.append("on");
    builder.append("youtube");
    builder.append(":");
    builder.append(BLANK_SPACE);
    builder.append("Mickey");
    builder.append("en");
    builder.append("de");
    builder.append(BLANK_SPACE);
    builder.append("stomende");
    builder.append("drol");
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Comment: You only write variables in capslock if they are constants. If they are you best use `private static final String BLANK_SPACE = " ";`.

Answer (score 1):

**A space is** only **a string containing the single** character **space**.

So you can append it exactly as appending any other string.

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("watch");
    builder.append(" ");
    builder.append("on");
    builder.append(" "); 
    // and so on
```

Remember also that the append method returns the StringBuilder so it is possible to join appends one after the other as follow

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("watch").append(" ");
    builder.append("on").append(" "); 
    // and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this, it's equivalent to using StringBuilder or StringJoiner, but smaller**

```
public class StringUnifier {

    String separator = "";
    List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    private String response = "";

    StringUnifier(String separator) {
        this.separator = separator;
    }

    StringUnifier add(String data) {
        if (!data.isEmpty()) {
            this.dataList.add(data);
        }
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        this.dataList.forEach(str -> {
            this.response += (str + this.separator);
        });
        return this.response.substring(0, this.response.length() - this.separator.length());
    }

}
```

MAIN

```
public class Main_Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringUnifier stringUnifier = new StringUnifier(" ");
        stringUnifier.add("columna1").add("columna2").add("columna3");
        System.out.println(stringUnifier.toString());
    }
}
```

RUN

output:

```
columna1 columna2 columna3
```